# Create list of uuids in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, uuid

Its possible to generate uuids with postgres (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-uuid/) Now I need to update my table where uuids are missing. I am not able to figure out how to achieve it. The column individual_uuid has a unique constraint. Any ideas? `???` should be replaced with the syntax I need.

```
update foo_table set individual_uuid = ???? where individual_uuid is null
```

not working:

```
update foo_table set individual_uuid = (SELECT uuid_generate_v1()) where individual_uuid is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usage of `SELECT uuid_generate_v1()` leads to the unexpected result that the same value gets used for every row, because the subselect is not correlated with values from the main query.

Use `uuid_generate_v1()` instead:

```
UPDATE foo_table 
SET    individual_uuid = uuid_generate_v1() 
WHERE  individual_uuid IS NULL;
```